# Dask HighLevelGraph short circuit computing

Tags: dataframe, dask, short-circuiting

I'm trying to take a DataFrame `ddf` and return a new DataFrame identical to `ddf` except when `ddf` has an empty partition it should point to the most recent non-empty component. For instance, if `ddf` has partitions `[P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6]` where `P2`, `P3`, and `P6` are empty Pandas DataFrames, then it returns the following Dask DataFrame: `[P1, P1, P1, P4, P5, P5]`. My code is

```py
name = 'prev-nonempty-' + tokenize(ddf)
meta = ddf._meta
dsk = dict()
def helper(A, B):
  return B if A.empty else A
dsk[(name, 0)] = (helper, (ddf._name, 0), None)
for i in range(1, len(ddf.divisions)-1):
    dsk[(name, i)] = (helper, (ddf._name, i), (name, i-1))
graph = HighLevelGraph.from_collections(name, dsk, dependencies=[ddf])
return new_dd_object(graph, name, meta, ddf.divisions)
```

My question is if there's a way to do short circuit computing in Dask HighLevelGraphs, so that the computation of the ith partition stops early if it finds a nonempty partition.

It says [here](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/spec.html) that

> In cases like `(add, 'x', 'y')`, functions like `add` receive concrete values instead of keys. A Dask scheduler replaces keys (like `x` and `y`) with their computed values (like `1` and `2`) *before* calling the `add` function.

which suggests you can't short-circuit it, but perhaps there are more sophisticated Dask scheduler tricks I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this with standard task graphs.  However, you might bake this logic into your function itself.

```
def func(accumulator, new_data):
    if is_done(accumulator):
        return accumulator
```

So you still run through all of the tasks, but they're very fast after you've met your condition.

You might also consider using Dask Futures, but this is a bit lower level.  https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html